# What is the benefit of implementing a DownloadCallback interface?

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, android-networking

I want to control a RaspberryPi via android app and plan to do this by defining an api on the raspberry and accessing it via the app.

On the Android Developer Guides I found the recommendation to implement a DownloadCallback interface.

My question is, why would I want to do that, if I can alternatively simply use an AsyncTask and make an HttpRequest?

Comment: If you write an AsyncTask, how will you notify the person who started it that it finished and what the result was?  Sure, if you're writing a 1 off you can do it directly there, but if you're writing a more generic class that implements a download, you'll need a callback interface.

Answer (score 0):

Using an AsyncTask for network calls is considered a bad idea. First, AsyncTask does not handle orientation correctly so you need to have more code put in so that the asynctask properly terminates (making sure it doesn't make calls to the finishing activity, making sure it doesn't hold any strong references to the finishing activity). You also cannot halt AsyncTask so lets say in your main UI thread, you want to stop the AsyncTask from performing the network call but you already started it. Well you are out of luck and you need to wait until it terminates on its own. (As mentioned in the comment below, this is not true. You can halt interrupt the thread of the AsyncTask to "cancel") Also, you cannot make parallel network requests in an AsyncTask easily.

Also this is more of a preference but using AsyncTask is more boilerplate code than I would like. Retrofit is my most preferred way of network operations.

DownloadCallback isn't about replacing the AsyncTask. It is just a way to communicate between your fragment (the one who started the network call) and the activity (the one who wants to know what the progress of the network call is) about the progress of your network operations. You can see here https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting that they are still using AsyncTask for network operations but they are using the DownloadCallback to notify the activity about the progress of your operation.

Comment: You can cancel an AsyncTask easily if you program it correctly.It has a cancel function, and will send an interruption exception to any IO when called.  Its no harder to cancel than any other thread.

Comment: That would be true but if your network operation was blocking then you wouldn't be able to cancel it.

Comment: @Steven THat's what the interruption is for.  It causes the IO to throw an InterruptedException, which you catch and return from (to end the thread).  This is all standard Java threading.  In fact its standard socket programming in general (C level socket calls do the same thing with returning -1 and an EINTR error code).

Comment: Actually a bettewr reason not to use AsyncTask for networking-  AsyncTasks are executed parallely on a single thread by default.  So by doing networking, which may take several seconds to timeout, on an AsyncTask you end up blocking every other AsyncTask in the app.  You're better off using a Thread for networking as a result.

Comment: You can supply a new executor for that though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197633/discussion-between-steven-and-gabe-sechan).

Comment: You can.  But its more boilerplate, and most people don't know to do that.  And easy to forget.  I'd just rather use a thread, and implement my own message passing for onPostExecute/onPreExecute (which is really all AsyncTask buys you).  Its definitely not wrong to do either.